# Firefox addon progress listener

Tags: firefox-addon, http-status-code-302

I am using this page to implement an address bar change listener.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners#Example.3a_Notification_when_the_value_in_Address_Bar_changes

This code does what it is supposed to do. When I navigate to a new page, it alerts the URL. However, if the URL I have is 302 or similar it causes an issue. It will alert the redirected URL and not the original URL. I need the URL before the request is sent to the server and the redirect happens. Is this possible?

Comment: In the Chrome browser I was able to acheive this using `webRequest.onBeforeRequest`.

    `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
      last_url = details.url;
     }
    }, {urls: [], types: ["main_frame"]});`

Comment: Are you saying you found a solution or workaround? If so, then you should post it as an Answer and accept it. If you can't, post reply to this comment.

Comment: No I am still looking for a solution. That is how chrome browser handles exactly what I am trying to do in Firefox. Didn't know if that would help anyone answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can check this via the onStateChange event.

```
var myExtension = {
    oldURL: null,

    init: function() {
        gBrowser.addProgressListener(this);
    },

    uninit: function() {
        gBrowser.removeProgressListener(this);
    },

    processNewURL: function() {},

    // nsIWebProgressListener
    QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI(["nsIWebProgressListener",
                                           "nsISupportsWeakReference"]),

    onLocationChange: function(aProgress, aRequest, aURI) {
        this.processNewURL(aURI);
    },

    onStateChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aStateFlags, aStatus) {
        if (!aRequest) return;

        if (aStateFlags & nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_START) {
            alert(aRequest.name);
    },

    onProgressChange: function() {},
    onStatusChange: function() {},
    onSecurityChange: function() {}
};

window.addEventListener("load", function() { myExtension.init() }, false);
window.addEventListener("unload", function() { myExtension.uninit() }, false);
```

See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIRequest

`aRequest` is a nsIRequest, whose property *name* is the URL of the request.

Comment: When I ran this code nothing happened. It did not alert any URL